# Mongoose - How selectionnate a specific field when return an array of referenced documents?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

***expected outcome: only get the "content"'s property of my referenced documents.***

I have a mongoose Model and I would filter the findOne result. I use the populate method to get reference of my object schema.

here my model:

```
function getAuthorPost(username){
  return User.findOne({ username })
    .populate('posts').exec((err, posts) => { 

        console.log("posts: ", posts) 
    })
}
```

it returns:

```
{ posts:                                                        
   [ { author: [Array],                                                 
       _id: 5c8c31e2e204566cd7ecef4a,                                   
       content: 'April' },                                              
     { author: [Array],                                                 
       _id: 5c8c31e2e204566cd7ecef4b,                                   
       content: 'Great spring' },                                       
     { author: [Array],                                                 
       _id: 5c8c31e2e204566cd7ecef4c,                                   
       content: 'Natural path' },                                       
     { author: [Array],                                           
       _id: 5c8c31e2e204566cd7ecef4d,                                   
       content: 'Better cherry' },                                     
     { author: [Array],                                                 
       _id: 5c8c31e2e204566cd7ecef4e,                                   
       content: 'Water life' } ],                           
  _id: 5c8c255fed727439d6d5b860,                                        
  username: 'Frank',                                         
  __v: 1
 }
```

I would just get the content field.

When I do

```
.populate('posts', {posts:"content"}).exec((err, posts)
```

it returns me the id as following:

```
{
  posts:                                                        
   [ { _id: 5c8c31e2e204566cd7ecef4a },                                 
     { _id: 5c8c31e2e204566cd7ecef4b },                                 
     { _id: 5c8c31e2e204566cd7ecef4c },                                 
     { _id: 5c8c31e2e204566cd7ecef4d },                                 
     { _id: 5c8c31e2e204566cd7ecef4e } ],                               
  _id: 5c8c255fed727439d6d5b860,                                        
  username: 'youmbo',                                                   
  __v: 1 
}
```

how could I get just the content field? 
thanks for any hint

Comment: Looking at [the docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#field-selection), what do you get with plain `.populate('posts', 'content')` ?

Comment: thanks for answer, the same I have already tested and I receive the whole document as in my first example without query: `{ posts:                                                        
   [ { author: [Array],                                                 
       _id: 5c8c31e2e204566cd7ecef4a,                                   
       content: 'April' },    ...`

I have assumed that was because my property is nested, hence my strategy: `{posts:"content"}`, so that it I'm at this point

Comment: Okay, [others have been there](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/5696#issuecomment-335113981) - how about `.populate({ path: 'posts', populate: { path: 'content' }});`?

Comment: thanks I will drill down on this hint, it returns undefined so I will get an eye to figure out how it works :)